# Web browsers stall on initial http request to certain websites, telnet works fine

Tags: internet

My internet connection is mostly working. A certain subset of websites, having little to nothing in common, exhibit this behavior:

When I try to load http://www.example.com in any web browser, it does not load for 10 seconds or more (sometimes not ever). During this time, Chrome's dev tools network timing tab says the connection is "Stalled". I don't have specific info on what other browsers think about the delay. If the delay ends (sometimes it never un-stalls), the rest of the request and response happen very quickly.

At the same time, I can do `telnet www.example.com 80` and `GET / HTTP/1.1\nhost: www.example.com\n\n` and get a response immediately.

This problem exists across multiple windows and mac desktops and laptops in my environment on a shared network infrastructure and internet connection. It exists on another internet connection through a different ISP in the same area. Could this problem be related to software common to all the affected computers?

Comment: Could be that site has external components (like ads, social media buttons, tracking stuff) that fail to load in a timely manner. telnet only gets index.html but does not parse it and load all those components.

Comment: @Dan the stall is happening prior to the very first DNS lookup for the website's domain.

Comment: Does it also occur if you use the IP address instead of name? Though telnet DNS resolution works, you mentioned that the issue occurs before the DNS lookup, so it's worth a quick test.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have a similar problem.

Comment: I did not. It went away on its own after a few days.